# Autocomplete and suggestions of Leaflet Search doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, leaflet

Good morning all,

I need your help with Leaflet search. I can't seem to find where the error is coming from, which is:
My search bar works fine but autocomplete with suggestions doesn't work, I don't know where it came from.
Also, but this is optional, can you help me to optimize the code for it to be fast to load on a web page (you can see that there is async but it's not enough given the amount of data I load).

Thanks for your help, I'll take everything into consideration.

```js
async function init(){
    var lat = 51.505;
    var lng = -0.09;
    var zoomLevel = 3;


    /**********************************************************/
    /*INIT MAP*/
    /**********************************************************/
    var mainLayer = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}?access_token={accessToken}', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
        maxZoom: 11,
        minZoom: 2,
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        zoomControl: false,
        accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYW1hdXJ5MDg0MDAiLCJhIjoiY2todWZ3dmtsMDR2cjJ0bzIwajc2NjBobyJ9.VXOjqAoE1IQ2DcCVSYlXOg'
    });
    var map = L.map('mapAgentsCentrimex', {
        center: [lat, lng],
        zoom: zoomLevel,
        layers: [mainLayer]
    });













    /**********************************************************/
    /*SEARCHBOX*/
    /**********************************************************/
    var data = us_states;
    var featuresLayer = new L.GeoJSON(data, {
        style: function(feature) {
            return {color: feature.properties.color };
        },
        onEachFeature: function(feature, marker) {
            marker.bindPopup('<h4 style="color:'+feature.properties.color+'">'+ feature.properties.name +'</h4>');
        }
    });

    map.addLayer(featuresLayer);

    var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
        position: 'topleft',
        layer: featuresLayer,
        propertyName: 'name',
        marker: false,
        moveToLocation: function(latlng, title, map) {
            //map.fitBounds( latlng.layer.getBounds() );
            var zoom = map.getBoundsZoom(latlng.layer.getBounds());
            map.setView(latlng, zoom); 
        }
    });

    searchControl.on('search:locationfound', function(e) {
        console.log('search:locationfound', );
        //map.removeLayer(this._markerSearch)

        e.layer.setStyle({fillColor: '#3f0', color: '#0f0'});
    }).on('search:collapsed', function(e) {

        featuresLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
            featuresLayer.resetStyle(layer);
        }); 
    });
    map.addControl( searchControl );  
























    /******************************************************************
    *********** MARKERS *********** 
    ******************************************************************/
    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
    var iconAirport = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'images/iconPlane.png',
        iconSize: [22, 34]
    });

    $.getJSON("json/airports.geojson", function(data){
        airport = $.each(data,function(key,val){
            var titleAirport = val.name;
            var latAiport = val.lat;
            var lngAirport = val.lon;

            markers.addLayer(L.marker([latAiport, lngAirport], {icon: iconAirport}).bindPopup('Name:' + titleAirport));
        });
    });
    map.addLayer(markers);

    
    var iconSeaport = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'images/iconBoat.png',
        iconSize: [22, 34]
    });


    var markersSeaport = L.markerClusterGroup();    
    $.getJSON("json/IFR_LOCATION_PORTS.geojson",function(data){

        var incidents = L.geoJson(data, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng){
                var marker = L.marker(latlng, {icon:iconSeaport});
                marker.bindPopup('Name:' + feature.properties.Name);
                return marker;
            },
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer){
                layer.addTo(markersSeaport);
            }
        });
        map.addLayer(markersSeaport);
    });

    L.control.layers({
        "Carte Pays": mainLayer
    }, {
        "Aérien": markers,
        "Maritime": markersSeaport
    }).addTo(map);
    map.zoomControl.remove();


    L.control.zoom({
        position:'bottomright'
    }).addTo(map);






















    /******************************************************************
    *********** GEOLOCATION *********** 
    ******************************************************************/
    var geolocButton = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});
    geolocButton.onAdd = (mapRef) => {
        var button = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'geoloc-button');
        button.innerHTML = '<span class="icon-location2"></span>';
        button.onclick = () => {
            mapRef.locate();
            button.disabled = true;
            mapRef.on('locationfound', (locEvent) => {
                var radius = locEvent.accuracy / 2;
                var point = locEvent.latlng;
                mapRef.setView(point, 8);
                button.disabled = false;
                L.circle(point, radius).addTo(mapRef).bindPopup('Vous êtes ici sur la carte').openPopup();
            });
            mapRef.on('locationerror', (err) =>{
                button.disabled = false;
            });
        }
        return button;
    }
    geolocButton.addTo(map);



























    /******************************************************************
    *********** COUNTRIES *********** 
    ******************************************************************/
    // Set color of countries
    function style(feature) {
        return {
            fillColor: '#ff5349',
            weight: 5,
            opacity: 0,
            color: '#ff5349',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0
        };
    }

    // Set Mouse Hover
    async function highlightFeature(e){
        var layer = e.target;
        
        layer.setStyle({
            fillColor: '#ff5349',
            weight: 4,
            opacity: 0.8,
            color: '#ff5349',
            dashArray: '',
            fillOpacity: .5
        });

        if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
            layer.bringToFront();
        }
    }

    async function highlightFeatureClick(e){
        var layer = e.target;

        layer.setStyle({
            weight: 5,
            color: '#ff5349',
            dashArray: '',
            fillOpacity: .7
        });

        if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
            layer.bringToFront();
        }
        info.update(layer.feature.properties);
        info.clickPays(layer.feature.properties);
    }


    // Back color Mouse Out
    async function resetHighlight(e) {
        geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
    }

    // Each Feature
    async function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            click: highlightFeatureClick
        });
    }

    // Display data to e.target inside wrapper
    var info = L.control();
    info.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); 
        this._div.setAttribute("id", "idBoxList");

        L.DomEvent
        .addListener(this._div, 'mouseover', function () {
            MapShowCommand(); 
        });     

        this.update();
        this.clickPays();
        return this._div;
    };
    info.update = function (props) {
        this._div.innerHTML = '<div class="wrapper--popup-agents"><h3 class="title-med">Agents disponibles</h3><div class="buttonListeAgent" id="buttonListeAgentId"><span class="icon-keyboard_arrow_down"></span></div><div class="textfield">Liste des agents disponibles selon le pays sélectionné.</div></div><div class="agents--wrapper"><div class="content"><ul class="listAgents"></ul></div></div>';
    };
    info.clickPays = function(props){       
        if (props) {
            this._div.classList.add("show");
            var el = document.getElementById('idBoxList');
            L.DomEvent.disableScrollPropagation(el);
            L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(el);

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });


            var name = props.name;
            var base_path = $('#url_base').val();

            $.ajax({
                url:"/map-agents",
                type:'POST',
                data:{name:name},
                dataType: "JSON",
                beforeSend: function () { 
                    $('.listAgents').append('<div class="spinner-border text-info" role="status"></div>');
                },
                success: function (response) {  
                    $.each(response, function (index) {
                        if (response[index].transport == 'M') {
                            var pathIcon = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/icon/picto-centrimex-bateau.png';
                        }
                        if (response[index].transport == 'A'){
                            var pathIcon = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/icon/picto-centrimex-avion.png';
                        } 
                        if (response[index].transport == 'MA') {
                            var pathIcon = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/icon/picto-centrimex-maritime-aerien.png';
                        }

                        var agents = '<li class="agents"><input type="hidden" class="agentId" name="idAgent" value="'+ response[index].id +'"><div class="leftSide"><h5 class="title">' + response[index].nom_fr_fr + '</h5><div class="name-firm">' + response[index].nameFirm + '<span>, ' + response[index].city + '</span></div></div><div class="rightSide"><img src="' + pathIcon + '" alt="Icon transport"></div></li>';
                        $('.listAgents').append(agents);
                    });


                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('.spinner-border.text-info').remove();
                },
                error: function (response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        }       
        else
        {
            this._div.classList.remove("show"); 
        }   
    };
    info.setPosition('bottomleft');
    info.addTo(map);

    async function refreshDataAgent(){
        $('.wrapper-overlay').html('<div class="wrapper--agent-map"></div>')
    }


    async function MapShowCommand() {
        $('.buttonListeAgent').off().on('click', function(){
            if ($('#idBoxList').hasClass("show")) {
                $('#idBoxList').removeClass("show");
                info.update();
            }
        });

        $('.listAgents li').off().on('click', function(){
            var el = document.getElementById('overlayMap');
            L.DomEvent.disableScrollPropagation(el);
            L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(el); 


            var idAgent = $(this).children('input').val();
            var base_path = $('#url_base').val();

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url:"/map-agents/agents",
                type:'POST',
                data:{idAgent:idAgent},
                dataType: "JSON",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('.wrapper-overlay').addClass('active'); 
                    $('.wrapper--agent-map').append('<div class="spinner-border text-info" role="status"></div>');
                },
                success: function (response) {  
                    var transport = '';

                    switch (response.transport){
                        case 'MA':
                        transport = '<li><img src="/images/icon/picto-centrimex-bateau.png"><span>Maritime</span></li><li><img src="/images/icon/picto-centrimex-avion.png"><span>Aérien</span></li>';
                        break;
                        case 'M':
                        transport = '<li><img src="/images/icon/picto-centrimex-bateau.png"><span>Maritime</span></li>';
                        break;
                        case 'A':
                        transport = '<li><img src="/images/icon/picto-centrimex-avion.png"><span>Aérien</span></li>';
                        break;
                        default:
                        transport = '<li><span class="whiteInput">Pas de transport renseigné</span></li>';
                    }

                    var wrapperContentAgent = '<div class="closePopUp"><span class="icon-cross"></span></div><div class="topSection"><div class="first"><h3>Compagnie</h3><ul class="compagnieList"></ul></div><div class="two"><h3>Mode de transport</h3><ul class="transportList"></ul></div><div class="three"><h3>Informations</h3><ul class="infosList"></ul></div></div><div class="middleSection"><div class="first"><h3>Référence client</h3><ul class="referenceList"></ul></div><div class="two"><div class="whitespace"></div><ul class="profitList"></ul></div></div><div class="bottomSection"><h3>Commentaire</h3><div class="contentComment"></div></div>';
                    $('.wrapper--agent-map').append(wrapperContentAgent);
                    $('.wrapper--agent-map').append('<input type="hidden" value="'+ response.id +'" name="idAgent">')
                    $('.compagnieList').append('<li>Nom Compagnie : '+ (response.nameFirm ? '<span>'+response.nameFirm+'</span>' : '<span class="whiteInput">Pas de nom de compagnie</span>') +'</li><li>Pays : '+ (response.nom_fr_fr ? '<span>'+response.nom_fr_fr+'</span>' : '<span class="whiteInput">Pas de pays</span>') +'</li><li>Ville : '+ (response.city ? '<span>'+response.city+'</span>' : '<span class="whiteInput">Pas de ville</span>') +'</li><li>Réseau : '+ (response.network ? '<span>'+response.nameNetwork+'</span>' : '<span class="whiteInput">Pas de réseau associé</span>') +'</li>');
                    $('.transportList').append(transport);
                    $('.infosList').append('<li>Nom : '+ (response.lastName ? '<span>'+response.lastName+'</span>' : '<span class="whiteInput">Pas de nom</span>') +'</li><li>Prénom : '+ (response.firstName ? '<span>'+response.firstName+'</span>' : '<span class="whiteInput">Pas de prénom</span>') +'</li><li>E-mail : '+ (response.mail ? '<span>'+response.mail+'</span>' : '<span class="whiteInput">Pas de mail</span>') +'</li><li>Téléphone : '+ (response.phone ? '<span>'+response.phone+'</span>' : '<span class="whiteInput">Pas de téléphone</span>') +'</li>');
                    $('.referenceList').append('<li>Référence compte client :  '+ (response.accountCustomer ? '<span>'+response.accountCustomer+'</span>' : '<span class="whiteInput">Pas de référence client</span>') +'</li><li>Référence compte fournisseur : '+ (response.accountProvider ? '<span>'+response.accountProvider+'</span>' : '<span class="whiteInput">Pas de référence fournisseur</span>') +'</li>');
                    $('.profitList').append('<li>ProfitShare : '+ (response.profitShare ? '<span>'+response.profitShare+'</span>' : '<span class="whiteInput">Pas de profitShare renseigné</span>') +'</li><li>Condition de Paiement : '+ (response.payementCondition ? '<span>'+response.payementCondition+'</span>' : '<span class="whiteInput">Pas de conditionde paiement renseigné</span>') +'</li><li>Réciprocité Business : '+ (response.business ? '<span>'+response.business+'</span>' : '<span class="whiteInput">Pas de réciprocité business renseignée</span>') +'</li>');
                    $('.contentComment').append((response.comment ? '<p>'+response.comment+'</p>' : '<span class="whiteInput">Pas de commentaire sur cette agent</span>'));
                    // if (response.supsension != null) {
                    //  $('.bottomSection').append('');
                    // }

                    $('.closePopUp').click(function(){
                        $('.wrapper-overlay').removeClass('active');
                        refreshDataAgent();
                    });
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('.spinner-border.text-info').remove();
                },
                error: function (response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
});
}


        // Call data inside geoJSON 
        $.getJSON("json/countries.geojson",function(data){
            geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
                style: style,
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(map);
        });
    }
```

```css
/************************************************************************************************/
/* MAP */
/************************************************************************************************/
#mapAgentsCentrimex{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 1;
}

#buttonScrollMap
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: white;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color: #4690be;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600; 
}

#buttonScrollMap:before
{
    content: '\e90e';
    font-family: icomoon;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


#buttonScrollMap:hover{ 
    text-decoration: none;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .info{
    background-color: #003366;
    color: white;
    width: 400px;
    float: none;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 80vh;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .buttonListeAgent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    opacity: .8;
    z-index: 999;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .buttonListeAgent:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    color: #FAFAFA;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .info.active{
    height: auto;
}


#mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper--popup-agents{
    padding: 30px;
}
#mapAgentsCentrimex .agents--wrapper{
    background-color: white;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .agents--wrapper .listAgents .agents {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
#mapAgentsCentrimex .agents--wrapper .listAgents .agents .leftSide{
    width: 60%;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .agents--wrapper .listAgents .agents .rightSide{
    width: 40%;
    position: relative;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .agents--wrapper .listAgents .agents .rightSide img{
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 3%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex ul.listAgents {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#mapAgentsCentrimex li.agents {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    color: black;
    padding: 20px;
}
#mapAgentsCentrimex li.agents:hover{
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
#mapAgentsCentrimex h5.title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    color: #4690be;
}
#mapAgentsCentrimex .name-firm {
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
#mapAgentsCentrimex .name-firm span{
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: capitalize;

}

#mapAgentsCentrimex  button.geoloc-button.leaflet-control {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border: none;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers, .leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.2) !important;
    border: none !important;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1001;
    display: none;
    cursor: initial;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay.active{
    display: block;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay .wrapper--agent-map{
    background-color: white;
    width: 85%;
    height: 80vh;
    min-width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    padding: 30px;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay .closePopUp{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay .closePopUp:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay .closePopUp .icon-cross{
    font-size: 22px;
    opacity: .7;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay h3{
    color: #4690be;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay .whitespace{
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}



#mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay ul li{
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-weight: 300;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay ul li span{
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
}


#mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay p{
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay ul li span.whiteInput{
    color: #eda60c;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay ul li img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay .topSection, #mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay .middleSection{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay .topSection .first, #mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay .topSection .two, #mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay .topSection .three{
    width: 33%;
    padding: 10px;
}

#mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay .middleSection .first, #mapAgentsCentrimex .wrapper-overlay .middleSection .two{
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="glob--map">
    <div id="mapAgentsCentrimex">
        <div class="wrapper-overlay" id="overlayMap">
            <div class="wrapper--agent-map">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#home-agents" id="buttonScrollMap"></a>
    <input type="hidden" id="url_base" value="{{ URL::asset('images/centrimex_logo.png') }}" name="">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem of autocomplete & suggestion resolve.
When you add librairies, make sure that you don't include leaflet-search.js & leaflet-search-geocoder.js in the same time. "leaflet-search-geocoder.js" blocked a few functions like Autocomplete.

But if you want to help me with the optimization of my script, the topic is still open